# Function not returning value in Python

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I have written a code to read a switch, temperature and date in python for Raspberry Pi. When I run each program individually without function definition, it runs fine. When I combine all it doesn't give any results.

```
def ReadSwitch():

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

    while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(17)
        if input_state == False:
            print(input_state)
            return input_state

def ReadTemprature():
    os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
    os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

    temp_sensor = 'sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041600c3c0ff/w1_slave'
    print(temp_sensor)

    f = open(temp_sensor, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')

    if temp_output!=-1:
        temp_string=lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
        temp_c=float(temp_string)/1000.0
        temp_f=temp_c * 9.0/5.0+32.0
        print(temp_c, temp_f)
        time.sleep(1)
        return temp_c

def GetDateTime():
    date = date.today()
    now = (date)
    return now


def InsertSmartBoxData():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "sa", db = "SmartPayloadBox")
    cur = db.cursor()

    try:
        temp = ReadTemprature()
        switch = ReadSwitch()
        time = GetDateTime()


        cur.execute("INSERT INTO SmartPayloadBox.SmartBoxData(temprature,tamper,time) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",(temp,switch,time))
        db.commit()           

    except:
        db.rollback()

    cur.close()
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that you have errors running this code, Can you update your question with the appropriate Traceback ?

Comment: You don't seem to actually be *calling* `InsertSmartBoxData` in this code. Please include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also looking at the code, `ReadSwitch` has a while loop that could block forever, and `ReadTemprature` can return `None` if `temp_output==-1`

Comment: No their is no error.

Comment: I have tried running without while loop . temp_output is around 25.

Comment: Getting perfect output fwhen run without functions

Answer (score 0):

You aren't seeing any errors because you swallow them up in your `except:` block -- all you do there is rollback the transaction.  Try putting a `raise` immediately after the `rollback` so you can see what went wrong (and add a finally with the `close()`):

```
try:
    # some stuff

except:
    db.rollback()
    raise

finally:
    cur.close()
```

The other possibility would be that the functions simply aren't being run.  As @match noted, nowhere in the code you showed us are you calling the master function, `InsertSmartBoxData`.

Comment: Hi Ethan, I tried adding raise and finally. I cannot see any error. As I said before, when I take this code out of function definetion, I am able to insert value of temp sensor, Switch and current date to database.

Answer (score 0):

I have no way of testing this code, as it is integrated to what I belive is a Raspberry-Pi or clone of such.

Assuming you are not measuring 0 Kelvin calibrated or scientific measurements, I am going to presume that you will never have to measure 0 K. (this will become clear later)

Let me analyse your code, and give some tips on improving your code. I will change some names of variables and functions to "*snake_case*" which is more pythonic.

First of all, your code does not have anyway of calling your major/main function. I would stronly advice to add the following 2 lines to the bottom of your code, this will call your main function when the script is ran:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    insert_smart_box_data()
```

This main function, you are enclosing all the code in a `try/except` block, which I believe you should change, so your calls to functions is outside the block, and the database update is inside the block, example:

```
def insert_smart_box_data():
    # call your functions
    temp = read_temprature()
    switch = read_switch()
    time = get_date_time()
    # open the database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "sa", db = "SmartPayloadBox")
    cur = db.cursor()    
    # update record
    try:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO SmartPayloadBox.SmartBoxData(temprature,tamper,time) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",(temp,switch,time))
        db.commit()           
    except:
        db.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        cur.close()
```

The first function you call is `read_temperature()`. You are assuming that the return has more than one line, or is valid at all. You need to return something if there is no valid read, the return value of this would be 0 Kelvin (= -273.15 C), so if you get that value, you know there is no actual reading. And you may change that to whatever you think is suitable, I just had to pick something. Example:

```
def read_temprature():
    # set variables
    temp_c = -273.15
    # do system commands
    os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
    os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
    # set filename
    temp_sensor = 'sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041600c3c0ff/w1_slave'
    print(temp_sensor)
    # read the file
    with open(temp_sensor, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    # check that you indeed have a lines[1]
    if len(lines) > 1:
        temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
        if temp_output != -1:
            temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
            temp_c = float(temp_string)/1000.0
            temp_f = temp_c * 9.0/5.0+32.0
            print(temp_c, temp_f)
            # not sure why you are sleeping for a second
            # consider taking this out
            time.sleep(1)
    return temp_c
```

The next action you do is to `read_switch()` which can be a indefinite loop if `input_state` remains `True`. Hence I would suggest a configurable `max_tries`. Example:

```
def read_switch(max_tries=10):
    # set default variables
    input_state = True
    # GPIO commands
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    # only loop until max_tries
    for _ in range(max_tries):
        input_state = GPIO.input(17)
        if input_state == False:
            print(input_state)
            break
    return input_state
```

you then the date/time function, can be simplified to:

```
def get_date_time():
    return date.today()
```

I have no way of testing, but putting it all together will now be something like this:

```
def read_switch(max_tries=10):
    # set default variables
    input_state = True
    # GPIO commands
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    # only loop until max_tries
    for _ in range(max_tries):
        input_state = GPIO.input(17)
        if input_state == False:
            print(input_state)
            break
    return input_state

def read_temprature():
    # set variables
    temp_c = -273.15
    # do system commands
    os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
    os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
    # set filename
    temp_sensor = 'sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041600c3c0ff/w1_slave'
    print(temp_sensor)
    # read the file
    with open(temp_sensor, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    # check that you indeed have a lines[1]
    if len(lines) > 1:
        temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
        if temp_output != '-1':
            temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
            temp_c = float(temp_string)/1000.0
            temp_f = temp_c * 9.0/5.0+32.0
            print(temp_c, temp_f)
            # not sure why you are sleeping for a second
            # consider taking this out
            time.sleep(1)
    return temp_c

def get_date_time():
    return date.today()

def insert_smart_box_data():
    # call your functions
    temp = read_temprature()
    switch = read_switch()
    time = get_date_time()
    # open the database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "sa", db = "SmartPayloadBox")
    cur = db.cursor()    
    # update record
    try:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO SmartPayloadBox.SmartBoxData(temprature,tamper,time) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",(temp,switch,time))
        db.commit()           
    except:
        db.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        cur.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    insert_smart_box_data()
```

Now, you do need to change your `try/except` block. You should only catch what you need to catch. Something like `except SomeError` and then `raise SomeExcpetion`. As I am not familiar with your db, you may have to change this yourself.